# Applying themes and styles in MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I come from ASP.NET Form development and now developing a MVC 3.0 application where when customer logs in she can select her different account from drop down:

The drop down contains:

> 1. Honda Car Insurance Account
> 2. Home Insurance Account
> 3. Ford Car Insurance Account.

When she selects one of the account the landing page changes with her historical details data etc. The application contains 4 more pages which has different contents for each account types.

In ASP.NET Form we could use themes and skins etc to apply the styles on the page based on which account the user has selected. However I don't see this seem to work on MVC.

Could anyone please suggest what would be the best way to achieve above in MVC?

> 1. Create one controller for each page and separarate views fro each accounts?
> 2. Should each page contentes be served by partial views?
> 3. Any other suggests?

**NB**: The JSON structure sent from controller is unique to each account type as each account have different properties.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a separate controller for each section. Then in the View folder for that controller, add a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file and inside it put

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Honda/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

This will point to the layout page for this controller (Honda controller, but use whatever names you want.)

Then in the `_Layout files` you can add different layouts, css, etc.

That's probably the simplest way to get drastically different looking sections to the same site. Plus you would still have your default `Home` and `Account` controllers to keep a standard landing page, etc.

You can still use partial views, and anything else you would like with this setup. It may even mean faster loading time for the end user since their browser won't have to download css and other files that it's not using.

**Edit**

Here is a bit more information, [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts with Razor from ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)

> Because this code executes at the start of each View, we no longer
>   need to explicitly set the Layout in any of our individual view files
>   (except if we wanted to override the default value above).
>
> Important: Because the _ViewStart.cshtml allows us to write code, we
>   can optionally make our Layout selection logic richer than just a
>   basic property set.  For example: we could vary the Layout template
>   that we use depending on what type of device is accessing the site –
>   and have a phone or tablet optimized layout for those devices, and a
>   desktop optimized layout for PCs/Laptops.  Or if we were building a
>   CMS system or common shared app that is used across multiple customers
>   we could select different layouts to use depending on the customer (or
>   their role) when accessing the site.
>
> This enables a lot of UI flexibility.  It also allows you to more
>   easily write view logic once, and avoid repeating it in multiple
>   places.

Comment: Thank you. _Layout.cshtml is same as master page, should not it be just ONE and not repeated for each views?

Comment: You can have multiple ones, just put them in the folder of the view for the controller your working with. Otherwise you would have to have  some logic in the root level `_Layout` page. MVC automatically will use the layout file that is in the controller's view folder, over the default root one. Also if you have a view with no layout, it will just use the default root one.